# Move to Specific Page in ScrollView While Hiding Between Pages - iOS

Tags: ios, view, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have Paged UIScrollVIew with 5 pages.

I have a problem where when I tap a button, I need to navigate from the 1st to 4th page. The problem is that it will show page 2 & 3 during this transition. I just want it to scroll to page 4 as if it were the next page in the scroll view.

Here is a diagram:

[image]

Any idea's on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to reposition your pages within the scroll view to make that happen seamlessly.  It probably means keeping track of what pages you've moved and perhaps a state engine that restores your original positions when you leave. It would probably be easier to make each page a subview and add that to your scroller, then you need just change each subviews frame as needed.